# Apache POI setAutobreaks(false) not functioning as expected

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to print an excel generated using the Apache POI and the manual page breaks are not functioning as expected I have set the following

```
    sheet.setAutobreaks(false);
    sheet.setRowBreak(50);
    sheet.setColumnBreak(20);
```

But as you can see below both the auto page break(doted lines) and the Manual page Breaks are coming and users have to manually drag the dotted lines to take a proper print out

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I went into the same problem. I wasn't able to eliminate the auto breaks, so I moved them using following code to the end of the last page:

```
sheet.setFitToPage(true);
XSSFPrintSetup printSetup = sheet.getPrintSetup()
printSetup.setFitWidth( (short) 1)
printSetup.setFitHeight( (short) 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code (groovy) generates two workbooks.

```
    testPageBreaks(false) //generates sheet with auto page breaks (see image 1)

    testPageBreaks(true) //generates sheet with auto page breaks but at the very last cell of the sheet (see image 2)

    def testPageBreaks(boolean fitToPage) {
        Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook()
        Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet()

        def r = sheet.createRow(90)
        def c = r.createCell(30)
        c.setCellValue("last cell")

        sheet.setRowBreak(30)
        sheet.setRowBreak(60)
        sheet.setRowBreak(90)

        if ( fitToPage ) { 
            sheet.setFitToPage(true)
            XSSFPrintSetup printSetup = sheet.getPrintSetup()
            printSetup.setFitWidth( (short) 1)
            printSetup.setFitHeight( (short) 0)
        }

        ByteArrayOutputStream ostream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
        wb.write(ostream)

        response.contentType = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
        response.setHeader('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename=test.xlsx")
        response.setIntHeader('Content-Length', ostream.size())
        ostream.writeTo(response.outputStream)
        response.outputStream.flush()
    }
```

Image 1 - testPageBreaks(false)
[image: Image 1 - testPageBreaks(false)]

Image 2 - testPageBreaks(true)
[image: Image 2 - testPageBreaks(true)]